# How to set all text in all slides to the same font?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I'm making a presentation that's looking a lot like the Frankenstein monster right now. There are 4 different fonts being used throughout all the slides, and I'd like to normalize this. I want to set all the text to the same font.
How can I do that?

I tried simply selecting all slides, but then you can't select the *Font* menu (and that's as far as my PowerPoint experience goes).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Select all the slides (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) using the `Outline` view. You can then change the **Font** for the selected text.

Answer (score 8):

In 2010 and 2013 its very simple

1) Home Tab > Replace (click More arrow) > Replace fonts

Answer (score 5):

You should edit [Slide Master](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/create-and-customize-a-slide-master-HA010078011.aspx). Set all fonts as the one you want in all slides in the Slide Master.

Comment: This is the more robust way, as this will also affect new slides.

Answer (score 2):

The suggestions above will allow you to change the font for any text in title/body/etc. placeholders (the "Click here" things that appear on new slides).  It won't affect other text; for that, you'd need to use a bit of VBA.

```
Sub TextFonts()

    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim oSh As Shape
    Dim sFontName As String

    ' Edit this as needed:
    sFontName = "Times New Roman"

    With ActivePresentation
        For Each oSl In .Slides
            For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
                With oSh
                    If .HasTextFrame Then
                        If .TextFrame.HasText Then
                            .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = sFontName
                        End If
                    End If
                End With
            Next
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Please explain more